# Servicing an interrupt vs servicing an exception

Tags: exception, embedded, interrupt, interrupt-handling

My understanding : An interrupt (hardware interrupt) occurs asynchronously generally been caused by an external event directly interrupting the CPU. The CPU will then vector to the particular ISR to handle the interrupt. 
Obviously an ISR cannot have a return value or have parameters passed because the event happen at anytime at any point of execution in our code.

With exceptions however, my understanding is that this is a software interrupt which is caused by a special instruction pd within the software.

I've heard that exceptions are handled in a similar fashion to handling an ISR. Can an exception handler in that case behave differently to an ISR , by taking arguments from the code and return a value, because we know where we were in our code when it was executed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *hardware exception* is not a *software interrupt*, you do not explicitly call it - it occurs on some hardware detectable error such as:

- invalid address
- invalid instruction
- invalid alignment
- divide-by-zero

You can of course write code to deliberately cause any of these and therefore use them as software interrupts, but then you may loose the utility of them as genuine error traps.  Exceptions are in some cases used for this purpose - for example in a processor without an FPU on an architecture where and FPU is an option, the invalid instruction handler can be used to implement software emulation of an FPU so that the compiler does not need to generate different code for FPU and non-FPU variants.  Similarly an invalid address exception can invoke a memory manager to implement a virtual memory swap-file (on devices with an MMU).

A software interrupt *is* explicitly called by an SWI instruction.  It's benefit over a straightforward function call is that the application does not need to know the location of the handler - that is determined by the vector table, and is often used to make operating system or BIOS calls in simple operating systems can dynamically load code, but that do not support dynamic-linking (MS-DOS for example worked in this way).

What hardware interrupts, software interrupts and exceptions all have in common is that they execute in different processor context that normal code - typically switching to an independent stack and automatically pushing registers (or using an alternate register bank).  They all operate via a vector table, and you cannot pass or return parameters via formal function parameter passing and return.  With SWI and forced-exceptions, it is possible to load values into specific registers or memory locations known to the handler.

The above are general principles - the precise details will vary between different architectures.  Consult technical reference for the specific device used.

Answer (score 1):

The term "exception" can mean completely different things.

There are "software exceptions" in the form of exception handling, as a high-level language feature in languages like C++. An "exception handler" in this context would be something like a  `try { } catch` block.

And there are "hardware exceptions" which is a term used by some CPU cores like PowerPC. These are a form of critical interrupts corresponding to an error state. An "exception handler" in this context would be similar to an interrupt vector table, although when a hardware exception occurs, there is usually nothing the software can do about it.

Hardware exceptions take no arguments and return no data, just like interrupts. Architectures like PowerPC separate hardware exceptions from hardware interrupts, where the former are various error states, and the later are interrupts from the application-specific hardware.

It isn't all that meaningful for a hardware exception to communicate with the software, as they would be generated from critical failures like wrong OP code executed, CPU clock gone bad, runaway code etc etc. That is, the execution environment has been compromised so there is nothing meaningful that the software executing in that environment can possibly do.

Comment: Will a divide-by-zero cause a hardware exception ? I still don't fully understand. Wouldn't a hardware exception be able to take arguments and return something to the code where it was triggered? Obviously with asynchronous interrupts it wouldn't make sense as they can happen anytime, anywhere

Comment: To add to Lundins otherwise excellent answer: most (all?) modern  architectures (>= 16bit) support one or more software exceptions, which serve as call facilities from user code to system code. These are not really "exceptions" like other exceptions because they are programmed into the instruction stream with a special instruction. The advantage of calling system software this way is the context switch (register stacking, stack switching, memory protection or memory management changes, disabling further interrupts, etc.)  which is necessary if you run a truly separated operating system.

Comment: @Engineer999 Return to the code how? For that to somehow make sense, it would mean that the code would be _expecting_ to divide by zero, or how would it otherwise be able to handle it? Divide by zero would mean you end up in some "constraint error trap" exception/interrupt. The only meaningful you can do from there is to spit out some error info or log the error, then "go hang yourself" by for example forcing a CPU reset. All of this is of course highly system-specific.

Comment: ok, perhaps i'm being mixed up with software interrupts. I was reading earlier that exceptions are software interrupts, hence a CPU instruction which causes an interrupt. Also can't we do a try and catch in high level software to handle the divide-by-zero? I'm a bit confused

Comment: @Engineer999 undefined instruction is a better example than a divide by zero.  first off you have to have a divide instruction if you do does it care about zero (well does it bother to have an exception or just provide some stock result). if you are talking about an fpu an fpu can be an add on depending on the processor it doesnt necessarily have to be fully integrated, so it can be somewhere between a peripheral and a part of the core.  an undefined instruction is something the core might care to cause an exception for.  but if fully integrated into the core, then divide by zero could be one.

Comment: @Lundin for an fpu an exception is or used to be a requirement for the spec, and you could/would return.  the hardware might not handle it but an isr could return with the "appropriately signed infinity" and continue the execution.   likewise data aborts and other, there are cases to keep going.  I mean how does a virtual machine work?  you let the guest code slam into an exception (talk to hardware it thinks is there) you take the data abort (mmu fault) do a simulation of the hardware it is trying to talk to and let it keep going.  aborting is not the only meaningful result.

Comment: but it is very system and system design specific.

Comment: @old_timer IIrc that's why PowerPC keeps fpu traps as interrupts and not as exceptions. I don't think this discussion is very meaningful without a specific hardware in mind though.

Comment: There actually are some CPUs that have a concept of *conditional exceptions* like the m68k with its `TRAPV` instruction.